# VSCode Liveserver and AWS Lambda API CORS Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been trying to set up an API in AWS through terraform. The setup is finally complete (I can include it if relevant), but I have noticed something interesting. When I start the frontend that contacts the API through VSCode's live server extension, I continuosly get a CORS error from my API gateway. I have tried running the frontend on the actual website where the site will make the requests from and there it works and the request goes through. Im confused at this point, since I think I set up my CORS headers correctly, but maybe Im missing something to allow localhost to work?